# Why ExecuteSqlRaw() method in EF core ignored some database keywords

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In Microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017, it documents the current Reserved Keywords.

My question is that, when I use one keyword "semanticsimilaritydetailstable" to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE semanticsimilaritydetailstable (
     column_name_1 int,
     column_name_2 nvarchar,
);
```

Firstly, I execute the above code in sql server **directly**, there will be **a SqlException**: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'semanticsimilaritydetailstable'". It means I should add "[ ]"for table name, because I'm trying to use the sql keyword to build the table.

And then, I exceute the sql **through EF core**, like:

```
string sql = "CREATE TABLE semanticsimilaritydetailstable (
     column_name_1 int,
     column_name_2 nvarchar,
)";

xxDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql);
```

The table named "semanticsimilaritydetailstable" will be created **successfully**. So, Why does this happen in EF croe ?(same in EF and ADO.NET)

**It should be notice that**, if the table is named for **another reserved keyword**, like WHERE, AND, COLUMN, creating the table in the above way **will both throw the same exception** "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'xxx'";

The below image shows the the actual statement  sent to the server when running EF query:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opeWc.png)

Does this design have any special use? Or maybe it's their potential bug?

Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Run SQL Profiler to capture the actual statement sent to the server when running EF query. Most likely the EF query will be sent with [].

Comment: Hi, Alex, thanks for your reply. I have run the SQL Profiler to capture the actual statement, but unfortunately, there are no [ ] in table name.

Comment: This "keyword" seems to become as such only in 2016. If some of your tests happen on SQL Server instances older than that, there will be no error. Check the output of `print @@version` for all instances you tried this at.

Comment: Thanks, Roger. According to your suggestion, I cheked the database  compatibility level. I find one of my database A's compatibility level is 2017, another one B, is 2008. When I directly executed code in sql server, I used the database A, and in EF, I used database B by mistake. So, this causes the above inconsistencies. Thanks for your answer!